# Show sensitive notification content when at trusted place

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, smart-lock

I have been trying to get sensitive notification content to only show when at a trusted location (android 5.1.1), however my attempts have so far been unsuccessful.

Is this possible to accomplish somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) and [AutoNotifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autonotification&hl=en)

## Instructions to Tasker:

1. Click the "+" Symbol
2. Select **Event** --> **UI** --> **Notification**
3. Tasker Action - Dismiss notification

You need to play around with this and it should work...

Kudos